# How to rewrite this problem in an equivalent SOCP form?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

Suppose I have problem like this:
\begin{equation*}
\min_x\left\{f^Tx:\sum^n_{i=1}\left\lvert x_i-x^0_i\right\rvert^{3/2} \le t\right\},
\end{equation*}
How can I recast it into SOCP?  I have some useful lemma such as
$z^{3/2}\le t \iff \exists w: wt\ge z^2, z\ge w^2$, and
$wt\ge z^2\iff \left\lVert \begin{array}{c}2z\\w-t\end{array}\right\rVert_2 \le w+t$.

Comment: It looks like that first lemma assumes $z\geq 0$, BTW.